# join two or more list with Lambda but not using the method or type "Join"

Tags: c#, linq

I am very new to C#. I have a method in  mapper class which accepts two parameters List1 and List2 as source and return a List of Model class which has fields defined. Fields come from both the list types.

Below is the class(SOHMapper)/method(Map)

```
public class SOHMapper : ISOHMapper
{
    public List<StockonHand> Map(List<WarehouseOnHand> warehouseonhands, List<SPR_SKU> SKus)
    {
       var Stockonhands = warehouseonhands.Join(SKus, x1 => x1.ItemNumber, x2 => x2.ItemId, (x1, x2) => new
        { x1.Quantity, x1.ProductStyleId, x1.ItemNumber, x2.GNumber, x2.Style }).Join(SKus,
       x1 => x1.ProductStyleId, x2 => x2.Style, (x1, x2) => new
        { x1.Quantity, x1.ItemNumber, x2.GNumber }).GroupBy(g => new { g.GNumber, g.ItemNumber })
        .Select(n => new StockonHand
       {
           DFUCode = "\"" + n.Key.GNumber + "\"",
           ItemNumber = "\"" + n.Key.ItemNumber + "\"",
           CompanyCode = "\"" + "VPAC" + "\"",
           NoOfCases = n.Sum(s => s.Quantity),
           Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
       }).ToList();

       return Stockonhands;
    }
}
```

Below is my Model Class ( Stockonhand) :

```
public class StockonHand
{
    public string DFUCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public decimal NoOfCases { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now this works fine and I get the required data. But the requirement is not to use the "Join" method/keyword in the lambda expression. Is there any other way I  can extract columns from both the List ? Is there a way "Where" method/keyword be used to get the fields from two different List ?

Comment: "But the requirement is not to use the "Join" method/keyword in the lambda expression." That's an odd requirement. *Why* can't you use `Join`? Whenever you have an odd requirement, please give details about the reason for the requirement - otherwise solutions may be suggested which meet the requirement, but violate some *other* unwritten requirement with the same root cause.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. It is not homework, rather actual project work in which I am stuck up. One of our technical supervisors asked not to use "Join". I haven't asked him why. I would do that and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In method syntax:

```
var result = warehouseonhands.SelectMany(w => SKus.Where(s => s.ItemId == w.ItemNumber)
                                                  .Select(s => new { w, s }));
```

In query syntax:

```
var result = from w in warehouseonhands
             from s in SKus
             where w.ItemNumber == s.ItemId
             select new { w, s };
```

Comment: @ArpanDG - great :)